# I was looking for a solution to add Hyperlink in Material Data Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagridview, hyperlink, material-ui

For example:
[refer this sample data grid](https://codesandbox.io/s/4be7oi?file=/demo.js).

I inserted [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09dja.png).

But was not able to make a link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `renderCell` and not `render`:

```
  {
    field: "age",
    headerName: "Age",
    type: "number",
    width: 110,
    renderCell: (rowData) => (
      <Link href={`/user?id=${rowData.id}`} target="_blank">
        {rowData.row.age}
      </Link>
    )
  }
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/datagriddemo-material-demo-forked-93d5nc?file=/demo.js

Answer (score -1):

just return the string like this way...

```
`<a href="${params.getValue("id")}">${params.getValue("id")}</a>`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).